# Unable to link Kafka MQTT source connecttor to InfluxDB sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, influxdb, confluent-schema-registry

We're trying to link a MQTT source connector to an InfluxDB sink connector. Right now the former is working fine but the latter gives the exception below:

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting
>   WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception. at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:484)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:265)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:182)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:150)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:146)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:190)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

This is the InfluxDB config file

```
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.influx.InfluxSinkConnector
connect.influx.url=http://localhost:8086
connect.influx.db=iot
tasks.max=1
topics=simMetrics
connect.influx.kcql=INSERT INTO sensorMetrics SELECT * FROM simMetrics WITHTIMESTAMP sys_time()
name=influxdb-sink
connect.influx.username=""
```

This is the message structure:

> { "timestamp": 1524572345184, "partition": 0, "key": { "topic":
>   "machine/sensor/mytopic/test", "id": "1" }, "offset": 0, "topic":
>   "simMetrics", "value": { "metrics": { "buzzer": 0, "led": 0, "water":
>   false, "buzzer_timestamp": 1524571762798, "temperature_timestamp":
>   1524571762816, "water_timestamp": 1524571762835, "fan": 0, "light":
>   500, "temperature": 27.371554588194957, "assetName": "SIMopcua",
>   "fan_timestamp": 1524571762791, "light_timestamp": 1524571762808,
>   "led_timestamp": 1524571762827 } } }

MQTT source connector config:

```
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.mqtt.source.MqttSourceConnector
name=mqtt-source
connect.mqtt.kcql=INSERT INTO simMetrics SELECT * FROM machine/sensor/mytopic/test WITHCONVERTER=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.source.JsonSimpleConverter
connect.mqtt.service.quality=1
connect.mqtt.hosts=tcp://192.168.208.203:1884
```

**UPDATE**
We found that the problem is on temperature values format.
Since we haven't configured the field's types, InfluxDB understands temperature values as double. All values having the decimal separator are correctly saved, the problem arise when Kafka sends values, without decimals part, omitting the decimal separator.
How can we fix this issue?
**PS:** Actual workaround is to add 0.00000001 to all incoming temperatures.

Comment: You've only posted the end of the error stack (`Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.`). If you check your connect worker log further up you'll see the actual error causing the exception.

Comment: Thank you Robin. Where I can find the log?

Comment: Kafka Connect's `stdout` - so it depends how you're running it. If you're using Confluent CLI then just `confluent log connect` will show the log.